# Using shell or bash to position block average large csv files

Tags: bash, shell, csv, awk, sed

Suppose I have some data that looks like this

```
1,2,2
3,4,5
4,5,6
1,2,3
4,5,6
1,2,2
```

contained in a csv file. Now I would like to position block average as such: add blocks (e.g two lines) and then take the average:

```
1,2,2
3,4,5
+
4,5,6
1,2,3
+
4,5,6
1,2,2
```

This would give

```
9,12,14
5,8,10
```

Averaged by the number of blocks (3) it becomes:

```
3,4,4.67
1.67,2.67,3.33
```

Is there an easy way to achieve this in awk, sed, grep or pure bash? My real data comes in GBs so it really needs to be quite efficient.

Comment: I am messing around with awk right now: `awk '{ sum += $1 } END { print sum }' file`. And I am trying to figure out how to do it in a block, so that it sums over all columns but also does it in block. I.e. in my above example I want to average by the position and the number of blocks. I could do this in python quickly but my files are too large for that to be an efficient route to go down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to get started:

```
$ cat tst.awk    
BEGIN{ FS=OFS="," }
{
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        sum[((NR-1)%2)+1,i] += $i
    }
}
END {
    for (j=1;j<=2;j++) {
        for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
            printf "%s%s", sum[j,i], (i<NF?OFS:ORS)
        }
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
9,12,14
5,8,10
```

I'll check in later to see if you have questions about how to complete it.

Comment: `BEGIN{ FS=OFS="," }
{
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
        sum[((NR+1)%2)+1,i] += $i
    }
}
END {
    for (j=1;j<=2;j++) {
        for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
            printf "%s%s", sum[j,i]/(NR/2), (i<NF?OFS:ORS)
        }
    }
}` Where I added position division with (NR/ Nr Rows in Block).

Comment: `(NR-1)%2+1` might be a bit easier to work with, particularly for larger values of 2.

Comment: @rici yeah using + instead of - was a typo, thanks for catching it.